# Modify attributes of certain tags adding a value

Tags: xslt, plone, diazo

like this example https://plone-theming-with-diazo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/snippets_diazo/recipes/index.html#add-attributes-on-the-fly
I need to modify the class of all of specific tag, adding a value (on the content side).

This rule does'nt work:

```
<xsl:template css:match="ul.navTreeLevel0 li">
        <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="./@class"/> no-bullet</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
```

I want to add the value "no-bullet" on any li tag inside a ul with "navTreeLevel0" class.

Diazo doesn't raise exceptions.

In the same rule file I've a similar situation, but in this case works :

```
<replace content="//div[contains(@class,'cell')]/@class">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
    <xsl:if test='contains(current(),"width-3:4")'>nine large-9 columns</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test='contains(current(),"width-2:3")'>height large-8 columns</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test='contains(current(),"width-1:2")'>six large-6 columns</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test='contains(current(),"width-1:3")'>four large-4 columns</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test='contains(current(),"width-1:4")'>three large-3 columns</xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test='contains(current(),"width-full")'>twelve large-12 columns</xsl:if>
    </xsl:attribute>
</replace>
```

What's the matter?
Vito

Answer (score 2):

It may be the same reason as in this similar question I read today: [diazo xsl:template not applying when inside secondary rules file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202134/diazo-xsltemplate-not-applying-when-inside-secondary-rules-file?rq=1)

Quoting the Diazo docs from there: "Inline XSL directives must be placed directly inside the root  tag and are applied unconditionally."

Well, apparently some xsl works outside of the root rules tag too, seeing that the other part of your code works.

If you replace the `css:match="..."` in your code with `match="obviously wrong[xsl"` does Diazo then raise an exception?  If not, then the likely reason is that your xsl is ignored and needs to be moved to the root roles tag.

Comment: Thank's Maurits. Modifying the css:match putting a obviously wrong syntax like "//*asd[]" Diazo raises exception (AssertionError: Unexpected symbol: '/' at 0).

Comment: The first rule I've wrote about is in the main rules.xml file, while the second one (the working one!) it's located in another rule called by an <xi:include>